# Math books to be read by a tenth grader

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I want to get some math books that a tenth grader going to eleventh should read. In our country,tenth graders know euclidean geometry, Coordinate geometry(only on straight lines),
Algebra pre-calculus(excluding determinants),permutations and combinations, Trig-1.

Now, What should the I read provided that I have already grounded the material in tenth grade and know serious proof writing?

I have collected the books below:
Michael Spivak- Calculus
Proofs that really count-Arthur Benjamin
Are there any good fun books for learning  basic Graph Theory(so that I may have some fun), Number Theory or Logic(books on discrete math)?

I have local books for C.G, Trig-2 and Trig-3. What other things can the tenth grader be given to read?

Comment: It's never a good idea to give academic advice to someone one knows nothing about.  Talk to teachers or other instructors who are familiar with your work.

Comment: Well, it depends. Are you interested in researching or focusing on further acadmics?

Comment: _Discrete mathematics with applications by Sussana S. Epp_ is a really good book for beginners. It has a chapter on _Graphs and Trees_ and even contains topics such as :
1. Elementary Number Theory
2. Set Theory
3. Recursions, Sequences and Induction
4. Functions & Relations
The best part is that this book also has chapters on developing logic for mathematics.  And can also be read by a 10th grader

Comment: @ RAHUL I just want to research on it and develop a good intuition on it.

Comment: @lulu I actually don't have anyone to view my work. It is not like that here.

Comment: How about something fun?  See the logical puzzle books by Raymond Smullyan, like *What is the Name of this Book?*

Comment: Weissman https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/

Comment: Large choice on OpenStax